# Hexagonal Architecture with Hibernate Reactive and Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, hexagonal-architecture, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

I am using Hexagonal Architecture, Hibernate Reactive with Panache and Quarkus in a Kotlin Project.

Transaction boundaries are set using `@ReactiveTransactional` annotation.

The problem is that I had to add the whole `Hibernate Reactive with Panache` dependency in the domain and application layers just to make this annotation available.

Is there a way to avoid this?

I was hoping it would be possible to create a domain annotation and then in the adapters layer replace it with the `@ReactiveTransactional` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the annotation from the  class, and wrap it into a service, and implement this service in the adapter layer using the annotation.

Comment: That would force me to write a lot of boilerplate code, since I would have to add an extra field in every class and wrap every call. Using an annotation is so much more convenient. I guess I'll have to either make a PR to Panache or write some custom annotation processor.

Comment: That's the price you have to pay if you want to be purist decoupling code. For some issues maybe it's better to break the rule. For example I use lombok at the domain. In your case, Vaughn Vernon in the red book examples uses @Transactional at the domain too. I think that I would use the framework annotation as well because writing a custom one is finally the same, not worth it. My opinion. Cheers

Comment: It's just that I try to follow best practices as much as possible, because most of the problems I see in software is because they were violated somewhere. But I can totally be pragmatic too, and in this case, it seems to be worth it like you said. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Don't** use database related dependencies inside the hexagon.

The idea is to decouple the business logic from the user interface and infrastructure. **Database logic should be placed into an adapter.**

It theory it sounds great, in practice that means tons of mappers i.e. boilerplate code. On the bright side you have a Kotlin, and not a Java project so this should be a bit less tedious than the alternative. Bear in mind that there are projects such as Dozer, MapStruct that can make the mapping process easier.